How to utilise the Shopify Section Rendering API in Theme App Extensions
How can you get the section_id of the section you want to dynamically render using the Section Rendering API. Since the theme app extensions let you create app blocks only, you don't really know the section where the block will be added and you can't make use of the name of the block eg. on a section my_custom_section.liquid, we can use my_custom_section as the id in a static section defined in the Section directory of the theme files.
How can i also pass in custom parameters to the section when using the Section Rendering API without relying on the content_for_header object workaround defined here. Shopify allows passing of their predefined parameters like filter.v.price.gte , filter.v.price.lte and sort_by as shown here .The request object in liquid doesn't give you access to query parameters also.
I have tried making use the solutions that are offered in this community discussions but nothing seem to work except the content_for header workaround https://community.shopify.com/c/online-store-and-theme/how-to-use-the-section-rendering-api/td-p/806580

Obtaining section_id for Dynamic Rendering
When using Shopify's app blocks within the Theme App Extension framework, you can't directly control or know in advance the section_id where your block will be placed. However, there are strategies to work around this:
Solution: Register a Placeholder div

Use a placeholder div with a known class or ID within your theme.
Dynamically find this placeholder in JavaScript after the page loads and fetch the relevant section using the Section Rendering API.


Add a placeholder in your liquid file:

   <!-- Add this line in your .liquid template where you want to dynamically inject the section -->
   <div id="dynamic-section-placeholder"></div>


Use JavaScript to dynamically insert the section:

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       // Get the placeholder element
       const placeholder = document.getElementById('dynamic-section-placeholder');
       
       if (placeholder) {
           // Render the section via AJAX call
           fetch(`/sections/your_section_id`)
               .then(response => response.text())
               .then(html => {
                   placeholder.innerHTML = html;
               })
               .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching section:', error));
       }
   });

Passing Custom Parameters to the Section
While Shopify's Section Rendering API allows predefined parameters, custom parameters can be passed using query strings, albeit indirectly.
Solution: Utilize URL Query Parameters

Use the URL to pass custom parameters and use JavaScript to read them and append them to your Section Rendering API request.


Modify your JavaScript to handle custom params:

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       const placeholder = document.getElementById('dynamic-section-placeholder');
       
       if (placeholder) {
           // Read URL params
           const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
           let paramsString = '';
           
           urlParams.forEach((value, key) => {
               paramsString += `&${key}=${value}`;
           });

           // Fetch the section with custom parameters
           fetch(`/sections/your_section_id?${paramsString}`)
               .then(response => response.text())
               .then(html => {
                   placeholder.innerHTML = html;
               })
               .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching section:', error));
       }
   });

In this pattern:

You add a placeholder div in your theme's liquid file.
Use JavaScript to dynamically insert the section content by making an AJAX request to Shopify's Section Rendering API.
Pass any custom parameters via URL query strings and append them to your section rendering request.

I have seen your job post on Upwork.
If you have any questions, please let me know.
